# Can a polling station in the UK shut early if everyone has voted?

Tags: united-kingdom, voting

If everyone on the voting list for a polling station had been to vote and have been marked off on the list the polling clerks have, would the polling station shut early? Or would it remain open until 10PM even though no one else could come in and vote?

Comment: Has it ever happened that all registered parties have voted in an area served by one polling station?

Comment: The [Handbook for polling station staff](https://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/sites/default/files/2019-09/UKPGE%20Polling%20Station%20Handbook%20English%20web.pdf) doesn't appear to envisage the possibility.

Comment: Various comments about elections in other countries deleted. Please don't post comments which aren't about the question.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

There's a process that's meant to be followed if someone arrives at a polling station to find that someone has already voted in their name or they're recorded as having received a postal vote (a 'tendered vote' can be made, although it isn't counted).

If the polling station closed early then this might be made impossible. For this reason it would not make sense to close early.

Comment: Are citizens in the UK allowed to watch the local counting? That would be a reason to unseal the ballot boxes at exactly the prescribed time.

Comment: @o.m., the count doesn't happen at the polling station.

Comment: @o.m Anyone can apply in advance (at least 3 weeks before the election date) to be a "registered observer" at the count. There is no charge except you have to provide a security pass  photo (and proof of your ID). In practice, the attendees will be people who have been canvassing for the candidates, not random members of the general public. It's not exactly an enthralling spectator experience!

Comment: @alephzero, if unregistered observers were a possibility, they'd have to wait if any shows up. Since they're not, the other reasons must be the explanation.

Comment: @o.m. you seem to be misunderstanding what happens at a UK polling station. When the poll closes, the ballot box(es) at each station are sealed and transported to a central venue for votes to be verified and counted. The count, by definition, starts after polling stations have already been closed, so a delay to the count for whatever reason would never be a reason for a polling station to remain open.

Comment: Postal votes can also be returned to the polling station until closing time, so unless all those have been received as well, they'd need to stay open.

Comment: @o.m. You asked if "citizens" in the UK could observe the count and I answered that question. But the question is irrelevant to the OP's question, since there is no local counting of votes at polling stations in the UK. There is a single count for all the votes in the constituency. The only "count" at the polling station is a record of the number of ballot papers issued during the voting period, which is checked against the number inside the ballot box as the first stage of the (centralized) counting process.

Comment: Absentee voters can also arrive at the polling station until closing time.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: ah? where does it happen then? I am genuinely interested as in France it is done at the polling station and everyone who votes is strongly encouraged to come and help with the counting.

Comment: @WoJ, the boxes are sealed and taken to counting centres. Judging from what I see on TV, some regions use sports centres. My constituency counts in the town hall. I don't know whether random people can watch the count, or only accredited candidates, their representatives, and media.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks! In France it is not even the watching by random people that  is encouraged, it is the counting itself.

Comment: @PeterTaylor According to alephzero above, any random person can watch (but they have to apply beforehand, not decide it would be a fun thing to do after leaving the pub).

Answer (score 69):

Polling hours are set out in Schedule I of the Representation of the People Act, 1983, as "between the hours of 7 in the morning and 10 at night".  There is nothing in the Act that allows a polling station to close early if all voters have voted.

Comment: This is the best answer because it actually refers to the act which governs polling booth hours

Comment: @FredStark While this *does* refer to the act which governs the polling booth hours, I believe that the other answer does a better job of explaining **why** it is important for the hours as defined in the act need to be followed, beyond just "it's the law"

Comment: @Chronocidal UK postal votes may be taken directly to one's local polling station on the day of the election (rather than posting them in advance). Those voting by post will not be on the list of expected voters at the polling station as they are not 'expected'. Would that be an adequate reason why it is important for the hours to be followed?

Comment: @rolinger Yes, and that's what the other answer says, which is why Chronocidal holds their view of said other answer.

Comment: Postal votes can be taken to **any** polling station in the constituency, not just the voter's local one, as they all end up at the same count centre. Also, candidates/agents and the police are allowed to witness the sealing of the ballot box "deposit slot" at the end of poll, and in many cases will turn up shortly before 10pm to do so.

Comment: The "Why" in the other answer is completely un-sourced. The real reason why is because the law says so. Which law? The "Representation of the People Act, 1983". Why did they make that rule? Ask the people that wrote the law

Comment: @JoeC you missed out the part in the act about if anyone is in line waiting to go at 10pm they will be allowed in to vote regardless of the time ..so it's not 7am until 10pm its `7am until 10pm and until the queue outside at 10pm has depleted to zero`, which (in theory) could be a long time

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica  no, they only have to be in the queue outside

Comment: I found the Electoral Commission website too, and the handbook for polling stations staff is quite clear.  I have deleted my comment.  I think this may have changed in the last decade - there was some fuss about people being turned away a few years ago.  I would be grateful if you would withdraw the accusation of "just fabricating".

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Definitely not a fabrication. I remember it too, and have been able to find a [news article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/england/london/8662185.stm). According to that the Commission said you need to have your ballot paper issued by 10pm. It could be that the rule has indeed changed (perhaps as a response to this incident).

Comment: @MrHeelis See above comments

Comment: cite: electoralcommission.org.uk/get-ready The Electoral Commission says: "Polling stations can get busy, however, especially towards the end of the day, and sometimes there can be a queue. "If you arrive at your polling station and are in a queue waiting to vote at 10pm, you will be able to vote." it says absolutely nothing about being inside and since MANY polling stations have no way to queue easily inside

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica on election days I have to prepare a voting station in a village near by and additionally  I vote in small village different to it. Both had signs outside near the gate that explicitly stated queuing outside was the 10pm  deadline (presumably because the two rural voting locations are small and offer no real privacy once you're in, the corridor is a right angle on both and then the second door is another right angle facing the polling staff, then a right angle to the 3 booths - in short if more than 3 people are waiting they could easily see who was voting what)